# Issues when adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

When I'm trying to create a foreign key linked to a primary key in another table I get:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`fayer`.`#sql-225c_1d3`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-225c_1d3_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I have checked that all tables are using innodb and the datatype are both "int".

What is the problem?

Comment: @ajsie: post the create table statement for the table you're trying to apply the foreign key to.

Answer (score 2):

You have rows that violate the constraint you're trying to add.

In this particular case, there are values in your `country_id` column that do not exist in `id` column of `countries` table.

Comment: i have edited so the value in country_id exists in id. but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Does it still give you the **same** error as above even after `OMG Ponies`  ' query returns no rows? Seems unlikely - if that's the case, there must be something else in play.